# Meaning of プレイ in this context?

Tags: words, meaning

So from my understanding, プレイ generally means play, but can also mean prey or pray? I was reading something, and I couldn't quite figure it out (actually, I read it as puree initially).

The line is, "おかゆプレイ　してえのに．．". Given the later line, "病人で遊んで　ませんか的な", I'm given the impression that the first line is supposed to indicate something like playing with your food.

Anyways, some help on understanding this would be quite appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The プレイ there is referring to [sexual roleplay](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%80%A7%E7%9A%84%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4) or any kind of sexual play. `〜プレイ` is often added jokingly to nouns or situations.

To give a relatively common example, if Mary's friend Susan was ignoring Mary's phone calls, Mary might jokingly say:

> スーザンに[放置プレイ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E7%BD%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4)されてる
>   Susan is doing an “ignore play” on me (like some kind of kinky game)

So, however ridiculous, おかゆプレイしたい is jokingly expressing the wish of doing a kinky “porridge play” with someone (whatever that entails!). Thus “病人で遊んでませんか的な” means something like “You're goofing around with a sick person”.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, given the context there. It means that the person who said "おかゆプレイ　してえのに．．" said that he wants to try feeding the patient porridge. Probably that is something that they usually don't do.